# WCF service: How to change visit address from localhost to real IP address

Tags: wcf, iis, post, localhost

I host my WCF service on IIS.

I following the introduction to *CREATE RESTful WCF Service API Using POST* http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201901/CREATE-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Using-POST-Step-By.

I can access the service with url as `http://localhost:16043/Service1.svc/PostSampleMethod/New`

But if I change the localhost to my local ip address, I can not access the service.

How can I configure to let remote machine to access my WCF service with its ip?

I can not find anywhere which can change my WCF service's default access ip adrress and port in Web.config file.

Here is my Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is IIS hosted? An address like localhost:16043 sounds like a casini or IIS express address.